# how can set timeout and active multi running builder in teamcity

Tags: performance, queue, teamcity

at the `TeamCity` in my current queue after any push and merge request automatic start to check all test and push in `NPM`. so if I have a bug in some testing agent in `TeamCity` will be a wait to complete that test for a long time and my queue will be not moved.

> so I want to make time out for this example after 4 min reject the
>   branch and move to next also I want run multi-agent for running
>   builder